# how to install gpu accelerated-gpu version pytorch on mac OS (M1)?

Tags: installation, pytorch, macos-big-sur

I 've successfully installed cpu version, shown as below,

[image]

I am using macOS 11.4, shown as below:
[image]

I read from pytorch website, saying it is supported on masOS 12.3 or later version, shown as below:

[image]

in https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac/

I am wondering if this is a way of running pytorch on m1 gpu without upgrading my OS from 11.4 to 12.3 or later version ...
(it will be much better and convenience for me if it is possbile to solve this issue without upgrading OS.)

Comment: Try https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Comment: hi, I saw they wrote '# MPS acceleration is available on MacOS 12.3+
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch', mine is macos 11.4 ... I 've successfully installed pytorch but cannot run gpu version. I am wondering if there's no other option instead but to upgrade my macos version ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple developer website](https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/), supports starts a macOS 12.3, like you mentioned.

Imo, it's safe to assume that there will be little to no effort to support an earlier version of macOS. What is your reason to not update macOS?

Comment: thank you. it seems that now I have no option but to upgrade my os version. becaus I am not sure if any issue will pop up after upgrading my os, and it is annoying to backup all required data (documents, passwords etc) beforehand .... and also I may have to reinstall every software I need again ....

Comment: I've upgraded my macOS with the help from apple workers in apple store ... and then I just found the battery health indicator dropped from 97% (as I remembed before the upgrade) to 95% ...